# How to set leader attribute to an AWS Beanstalk instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having the below configuration in AWS Beanstalk

Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling
Number instances: 1 - 4

When a new instance is created, crontab is added for the new instance. So duplication of crons are executing. How can I set the crontab to rub only in one instance?

I am using .ebextensions in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify which instance is assigned the leader flag; there is an election process that determines which instance "wins".

That being said, you can use the `leader_only` flag in your `.ebextensions/crontab.config` file when you create the crontab. It might look something like this:

```
container_commands:
  01_create_crontab:
    command: "> /etc/cron.d/mycrontab && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/mycrontab"
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: remember that this solution is not reliable, AWS may change the 'leader' instance during scale-up/scale-down process , or even during the platform or ENV variables update.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on setting up cronjobs on deploy, which is unreliable (AWS may change 'leaders' after deploy), you should think about checking or setting the leader instance in the actual job code.

See https://github.com/dignoe/whenever-elasticbeanstalk/blob/master/bin/ensure_one_cron_leader , it's Ruby, not PHP, but the code is readable.

Deploy the crontab definition to all instances, but when the job is triggered:
* use distributed Mutex lock (either Redis/ElastiCache or database backed) - only one worker will be able to pass
* OR, may be more complicated to code: check on all instances if they are leaders, if there is none, set one, and then continue the job only on the leader.

Alternatively you'd have to switch to using Worker Tier or SNS/SQS systems. Set up the schedule in cron.yml, define a POST endpoint that accepts request from localhost only (there will be a local daemon process running on the worker server, that listens for SQS messages and triggers jobs => POST). Not an ideal solution but it's a trade-off, there are other benefits of AWS EB platform.